# Python Django how to save many to one relationship JSON data in sqlite

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I was wondering how I should go about saving data items in tables which have a many to one relationship with a model

Here is the code that I got so far:

`models.py:`

```
class Recipes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    style = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    brewer = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='All Grain')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1')
    batch_size = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    boil_size = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    boil_time = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    efficiency = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=75.0)
    ibu = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    abv = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    notes = models.TextField(default='')
    carbonation = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    primary_age = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default = 0)
    secondary_age = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default = 0)
    age = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default = 0)
    __fermentables = []
  
    @classmethod
    def create(cls,attr):
        recipe = cls()
        # do something with the book
        for k in Recipes._meta.fields:
            if  k.name in attr:
                setattr(recipe,k.name,attr[k.name])
        return recipe
    @classmethod
    def addFermentables(self,items):

       for itm in items:
           
           self.__fermentables.append(itm)
         
           return self.__fermentables

    @classmethod
    def addHops(self,items):
       for i in items:
           return i
           

  
class RecipeFermentable(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    extract = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    color= models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    fermentable = models.ForeignKey(Fermentable, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    def create(cls, attr, recipes):
        fermentables = cls()
        # do something with the book
        for k in RecipeFermentable._meta.fields:
            if  k.name in attr:
                setattr(recipe,k.name,attr[k.name])
        return fermentables

class RecipeHops(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    alpha = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    use = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    hop = models.ForeignKey(Hop, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    time = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
```

`views.py:`

```
def recipes(request):
    recipes = Recipes.objects.all()
    recipeFermentableFormset = formset_factory(RecipeFermentableForm, extra=1)
    recipeHopFormset = formset_factory(RecipeHopForm, extra=1)
    RecipeMiscFormSet= formset_factory(RecipeMiscForm, extra=1)
    RecipeYeastFormSet = formset_factory(RecipeYeastForm,extra=1)
    RecipeMashFormSet = formset_factory(RecipeMashForm,extra=1)
    return render(request, 'recipes.html', {'recipes':recipes,"recipe_form" :RecipeForm(auto_id="recipe_%s"), 
    "recipe_fermentableformset":recipeFermentableFormset(prefix='fermentable'),
    "recipe_hopformset":recipeHopFormset(prefix='hop'),


def saveRecipe(request):
        try:
            data=json.loads(request.read())
            print("printing values")
            print(data["name"])  #prints here works
            recipe = Recipes.create(attr=data)
            recipe.name = data["name"]
            recipe.save()
            recipe.addFermentables(items=data["fermentables"])
            recipe.addHops(items=data["hops"])
            return  HttpResponse(serialize('json', [recipe]),  content_type='application/json')
        except:
           
            return HttpResponse("error")
```

So basically when the user fills the forms and presses on the save button, the `saveRecipe` function gets called. In the function I have the `recipe.save()` which saves to the base Recipes table in the database.

However, I want to also save the RecipeFermentable and RecipeHops which have a many to one relationship with the Recipes model to their specific tables in the sqlite database.

And I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Could someone please help me by telling me whether the code I have so far is correct and how I should continue with saving the other data?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to establish relationship between newly added row of "Recipe" model with existing rows of "RecipeFermentable" and "RecipeHops".Try below approach in your view function.

```
recipe_fermentable_obj = RecipeFermentable.objects.get(id="identifier")
recipe_hops_obj = RecipeHops.objects.get(id="identifier")
# after saving recipe into "Recipe" model.
recipe.recipefermentable_set.add(recipe_fermentable_obj)
recipe.recipehops_set.add(recipe_hops_obj)
recipe.save() # calling again
```

If you want to create new rows in "RecipeFermentable" and "RecipeHops" while creating new row in "Recipe" model, try below approach.

```
# create recipe object and save()
recipe_obj.save()
# create recipe_fermentable object with recipe obj for foreign key field.
RecipeFermentable.objects.create(recipe=recipe_obj, .....)
RecipeHops.objects.create(recipe=recipe_obj, .....)
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/